# xmlwriter as input for xmlreader

Tags: c#, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I am trying to create a xml-structre from a name/value-pairs. This works with a xmlwriter. Now I would like to transform this xml.

I think that the best way is to use the xmlwriter as source for the xmlreader to to the transform. But I don't know how to set the xmlwriter as source for the xmlreader.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd6aw1b.aspx

Comment: Unless it is more than 100 MByte or so, you're much better of with XDocument.

Comment: Hi. I edited the first posting with sourcecode and the description of my problem. Maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a MemoryStream for example.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
{
    // Do some stuff with writer
}

stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Reset stream position to read from the beginning.

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    // Do some stuff with reader
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I can compile it. But when I use stream.ToString() the result is empty. How can I read the String? (sorry newbie)

Comment: You can use the reader instead. Everything you write into the stream using the writer, you can read inside the reader with its ReadInnerXML-Method (returns a string).

Comment: Two corrections - either call `writer.Flush()` or dispose `writer` before reading from `stream`. Also call `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` before reading to reset the stream position to the beginning.